# Cannot add elements into list inside map body

Tags: dart

When executing the following code , no items added to list named x , Any idea why ?
I know if i loop normally over it, it will work but i just wonder why it behaves like that

```
    List<int> x = [];
    List<int> y = [1,2,3,4];
    y.map((item) => x.add(item +2));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`.map()`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.19.1/dart-core/Iterable/map.html) method returns a lazily evaluated `Iterable`:

> Returns a new lazy Iterable with elements that are created by calling toElement on each element of this Iterable in iteration order.

Since you don't consume the returned `Iterable`, it will not trigger the method provided to `map()` and nothing happens.

You can instead use the [`forEach()`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.19.1/dart-core/Iterable/forEach.html) method which will run on each elements in your list immediately.